# Cómo ejecutar una función sin onclick y sin agregarlo al body

Tags: javascript

Me interesa saber cómo hacer para tener la función ya cargada al entrar en la página sin tener que dar click en un botón o cargarlo en el body

```js
function color(){
var x = document.getElementById("box");
x.className = "cajas";
}
```

```css
.cajas{
background-color: #ddd;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.cajas > span{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>


<button onclick="color()">Color</button>
```

Comment: un bloque `<script>` con javascript, inmediatamente después de declarado el elemento ya lo puede ver y modificarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente llamá a la función después de declararla.

```js
function color() {
    var x = document.getElementById("box");
    x.className = "cajas";
}
color();
```

```css
.cajas{
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.cajas > span{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

El HTML que recibe el navegador queda así:

```
<body>
  <div id="box" class="cajas">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function color() {
        var x = document.getElementById("box");
        x.className = "cajas";
      }
      color();
  </script>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
</body>
```